# Declaring an int value outside of inner class

Tags: java, android

How do i get the value of the int count to be declare in a setText outside of its inner class?

```
    model.getSearch().observe(this, new Observer<List<Sight>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Sight> searchList) {
            adaptersearch = new SearchAdapter(SearchResults.this, searchList);
            searchhList.setAdapter(adaptersearch);
            int count = 0;
            if (adaptersearch != null) {
                count = adaptersearch.getItemCount();

            }


        }
    });  
    apptxt.setText(count +name+ "items");
```

At the minute it just comes up with the error cannot resolve count.

Comment: Can you provide more details ? Do you need to set the text outside the onChanged method? I mean whenever the count changes shouldn't the apptxt update the text? You should provide the whole picture of your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write to a variable (change the value of the variable ) that has been initialized in outer class from an inner class.

there is a  workaround to do it is to create a final array of int with one value, then you can access it in your inner class.

keep in mind that this is not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If this is really the scenario you are looking for one way of doing it is using an int wrapper or using AtomicInteger which is helpful should there be threads involved there:

```
final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
model.getSearch().observe(this, new Observer<List<Sight>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Sight> searchList) {
            adaptersearch = new SearchAdapter(SearchResults.this, searchList);
            searchhList.setAdapter(adaptersearch);
            if (adaptersearch != null) {
                count.set(adaptersearch.getItemCount());

            }


        }
    });  
    apptxt.setText(count.get() +name+ "items");
```

What you are experiencing is that the reference should be final in that case and therefore you must change the value inside the object as you cannot change the reference.